# Issue retrieving attachment filename with javaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, attachment

i've a plugin that should process some mails, so i need to get attachments from an imap mail and do some stuff.

All seem to work but i've a single mail that have a strange attachment header and i'm not able to get it correctly, here the attachment header:

```
    --_01d0aeb2-3f01-4153-9121-66b7af6924f1_
Content-Type: application/msword
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=
    "=?iso-8859-1?Q?Atto_Aziendale_(xxx=E0_del_xxx_xxx_-_xxx)=2C_Pr?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?of.xxx_xxx_-_Dr.xxx_xxx.doc?="
```

"x" are for privacy but that should not be important, the problem is that when i try to get the filename of this attachment with javaMail:

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(mailPart);
String filename = att.getFilename();
```

i get only this: "Atto Aziendale (xxx del xxx xxx - xxx), Pr"

seem that it doesn't read the second line.

I've also tried to get the filename in another way:

```
mailPart.getHeader("Content-Disposition").getAttribute("filename").toString();
```

and that return: filename="=?iso-8859-1?Q?Atto_Aziendale_(xxx=E0_del_xxx_xxx_-_xxx)=2C_Pr?==?iso-8859-1?Q?of.xxx_xxx_-_Dr.xxx_xxx.doc?="

so it seem that the attribute is correctly readed, but if i try to get:

```
mailPart.getHeader("Content-Disposition").getAttribute("filename").getValue();
```

then i get again a truncated filename: "Atto Aziendale (xxx del xxx xxx - xxx), Pr"

anyone know how to get the complete filename or how i should decode the filename attribute?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using IMAP, the IMAP server is parsing the mail headers and returning the parsed values to the JavaMail client.  Your Content-Disposition header has several continuation lines.  The IMAP server needs to properly combine those continuation lines and return the parameter values.  It looks like the server is omitting the whitespace implied by the continuation line and joining the "?=" with the "=?".  Without whitespace between them, they appear to be one encoded word instead of two, which likely explains why you're getting the wrong results when decoding them.

Try setting the System property "mail.mime.decodetext.strict" to "false"; this may allow JavaMail to decode the value.  See the [javadocs for the javax.mail.internet package](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html) for details.

Comment: your link points nowhere anymore. I am not sure what you mean by setting System property.

Comment: The JavaMail documentation is now [here](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html).  Set a System property using [System.setProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).